# ¿Cómo centro este menú desplegable (dropdown)?

Tags: html, css

Estoy siguiendo el código de un tutorial básico para hacer un menú del tipo `dropdown`. Y estoy tratando de aplicar por mi cuenta código CSS que me permita centrar en la pagina, el menú horizontal. Sin embargo no he podido hacerlo.

Y aca esta el CSS y el HTML que estoy aplicando...

```css
nav {
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto 20px;
 border: 1px solid #222;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #FBE080;
 font: 16px Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

nav ul {
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
    
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul:after {
 content:".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}

nav li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li a{
 display:block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-left: 1px solid #999;
 border-right: 1px solid #222;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:focus{
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

nav li:firt-child a{
 border-left: none;
}

nav li.ultimo a {
 border-right: none;
}

nav li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}

nav a span { 
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
}

nav ul a span { 
    -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

nav ul ul { 
    display: none; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    background: #FDEDB2; 
}
nav ul ul li { 
    float: none; 
}
nav ul ul a { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    border-left: none; 
    border-right: none; 
    font-size: 14px; 
}
nav ul ul a:hover { 
    background-color: #FBE080; 
}

nav { 
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 22px 90deg, #FBE080, #999); 
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 70%, from(#999), to(#FBE080));  
}

nav li:hover { 
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100px 90deg, #999, #FBE080); 
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 70%, from(#FBE080), to(#999)); 
}

nav ul ul { 
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8); 
    background-color:rgba(253,237,178,0.8); 
}
nav ul ul li { 
    border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
nav ul ul li.ultimo { 
    border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;  
}
nav ul ul a:hover { 
    background-color:rgba(251,224,128,.9); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Men&uacute; de Navegaci&oacute;n</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo2.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav id="MenuNav">
   <ul>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 1">Men&uacute; 1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 2">Men&uacute; 2<span>^</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 1">Submen&uacute; 1</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 2">Submen&uacute; 2</a> </li>
      <li class="ultimo"> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 3">Submen&uacute; 3</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 3">Men&uacute; 3</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 4">Men&uacute; 4<span>^</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 4">Submen&uacute; 4</a> </li>
      <li class="ultimo"> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 5">Submen&uacute; 5</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 5">Men&uacute; 5</a> </li> 
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes centrar el menú aplicando los siguientes pasos:

- Haz que el `nav` centre su contenido añadiendo `text-align:center`.
- Haz que la lista tenga `display:inline-block`, de este modo no ocupará todo el ancho del padre y se centrará dentro del `nav`.
- Ahora el problema es que queda un espacio "en blanco" bajo la lista, para solucionarlo puedes especificar un alto para el `nav` (p.e.: la lista tiene un alto de 39px).

De este modo el `nav` seguirá ocupando el 100% de la pantalla y sólo la lista se centrará dentro. Aquí puedes ver los cambios funcionando:

```css
nav {
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto 20px;
 border: 1px solid #222;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #FBE080;
 font: 16px Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    height:39px;
}

nav ul {
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul:after {
 content:".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}

nav li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li a{
 display:block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-left: 1px solid #999;
 border-right: 1px solid #222;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:focus{
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

nav li:firt-child a{
 border-left: none;
}

nav li.ultimo a {
 border-right: none;
}

nav li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}

nav a span { 
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
}

nav ul a span { 
    -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

nav ul ul { 
    display: none; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    background: #FDEDB2; 
}
nav ul ul li { 
    float: none; 
}
nav ul ul a { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    border-left: none; 
    border-right: none; 
    font-size: 14px; 
}
nav ul ul a:hover { 
    background-color: #FBE080; 
}

nav { 
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 22px 90deg, #FBE080, #999); 
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 70%, from(#999), to(#FBE080));  
}

nav li:hover { 
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100px 90deg, #999, #FBE080); 
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 70%, from(#FBE080), to(#999)); 
}

nav ul ul { 
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8); 
    background-color:rgba(253,237,178,0.8); 
}
nav ul ul li { 
    border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
nav ul ul li.ultimo { 
    border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;  
}
nav ul ul a:hover { 
    background-color:rgba(251,224,128,.9); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Men&uacute; de Navegaci&oacute;n</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo2.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav id="MenuNav">
   <ul>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 1">Men&uacute; 1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 2">Men&uacute; 2<span>^</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 1">Submen&uacute; 1</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 2">Submen&uacute; 2</a> </li>
      <li class="ultimo"> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 3">Submen&uacute; 3</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 3">Men&uacute; 3</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 4">Men&uacute; 4<span>^</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 4">Submen&uacute; 4</a> </li>
      <li class="ultimo"> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 5">Submen&uacute; 5</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 5">Men&uacute; 5</a> </li> 
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

```css
.Wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 0 auto 20px;
 border: 1px solid #222;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #FBE080;
 font: 16px Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

nav ul {
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
    
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul:after {
 content:".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}

nav li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li a{
 display:block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-left: 1px solid #999;
 border-right: 1px solid #222;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:focus{
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

nav li:firt-child a{
 border-left: none;
}

nav li.ultimo a {
 border-right: none;
}

nav li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}

nav a span { 
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
}

nav ul a span { 
    -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

nav ul ul { 
    display: none; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    background: #FDEDB2; 
}
nav ul ul li { 
    float: none; 
}
nav ul ul a { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    border-left: none; 
    border-right: none; 
    font-size: 14px; 
}
nav ul ul a:hover { 
    background-color: #FBE080; 
}

nav { 
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 22px 90deg, #FBE080, #999); 
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 70%, from(#999), to(#FBE080));  
}

nav li:hover { 
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100px 90deg, #999, #FBE080); 
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 70%, from(#FBE080), to(#999)); 
}

nav ul ul { 
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8); 
    background-color:rgba(253,237,178,0.8); 
}
nav ul ul li { 
    border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
nav ul ul li.ultimo { 
    border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;  
}
nav ul ul a:hover { 
    background-color:rgba(251,224,128,.9); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Men&uacute; de Navegaci&oacute;n</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo2.css">
 </head>
 <body>
        <div class="Wrapper">
  <nav id="MenuNav">
   <ul>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 1">Men&uacute; 1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 2">Men&uacute; 2<span>^</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 1">Submen&uacute; 1</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 2">Submen&uacute; 2</a> </li>
      <li class="ultimo"> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 3">Submen&uacute; 3</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 3">Men&uacute; 3</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 4">Men&uacute; 4<span>^</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 4">Submen&uacute; 4</a> </li>
      <li class="ultimo"> <a href="#" title="SubMenu 5">Submen&uacute; 5</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
    <li> <a href="#" title="Menu 5">Men&uacute; 5</a> </li> 
   </ul>
  </nav>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unicamente agreaste text-align: center; a la class wrapper que agregaste y al ul dentro de nav, no? Por cierto... con tu edición la barra del menú no abarca la pagina completa, como esta originalmente.